# Labouchere system (roulette)

Tags: probability

**Question:** The *Labouchere system* for roulette is played as follows. Write down a list of numbers, usually 1, 2, 3, 4. Bet the sum of the first and last, 1 + 4 = 5, on red. If you win, delete the first and last numbers from your list. If you lose, add the amount that you last bet to the end of your list. Then use the new list and bet the sum of the first and last numbers (if there is only one number, bet that amount). Continue until your list becomes empty. Show that, if this happens, you win the sum, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10, of your original list.

---

**Answer:** 
Each time you win, you either win an amount that you have already lost or one of the original numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, and hence your net winning is just the sum of these four numbers.

---

I can't quite understand what they mean by "you either win an amount that you have already lost or one of the original numbers 1, 2, 3, 4". Can't quite see it. For example if I lose two times, I'd be at (-11), and if I then win, I'd be at (-11)+(1+6)=(-4), so where did I win an amount I've already lost or where are the 1, 2, 3 or 4?

Comment: I do not think either that this answer is a good formulation why the player wins the sum of the four original numbers. The player wins back ONE lost amount (formulated as "an amount") , but it is not easy to see this way that the claim is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following proof that the player wins the sum of the four original numbers, if he\she manages to empty the list.

We denote :

$S$ : sum of the original four numbers

$T$ : sum of the numbers of the current list.

Claim : The saldo is always $S-T$

At the beginning, the player starts with saldo $0$ and $S=T$.

- Whenever the player wins, the number $T$ decreases by the amount that was bet because two numbers summing up to the amount are removed from the list. This means that $S-T$ increases by the won amount.
- Whenever the player loses, $T$ increases by the lost amount. Hence $S-T$ decreases by the amount that was bet.

Hence , $S-T$ always is the current saldo. If $T=0$, the player has saldo $S$, so he\shw won the sum of the original $4$ numbers.

Comment: By 'saldo' you mean (winnings – losses), right?

Comment: @Max Yes, exactly.